# Is it possible to reply when reading emails with Imap or node-imap?

Tags: node.js, imap, node-imap

I'm connecting to the imap outlook server, in this case when reading an email; after applying a validation I should reply to the sender, from the address; for example, if the email sender is unknown based on a db query; I should reply to the sender:

"Email not registered on the db..."

I this possible with node-imap in node js?

Comment: `imap` as a protocol does not supporting sending of email.  For that, you would use the smtp protocol to an smtp server.  Your email provider should also have an smtp server that you are allowed to use for sending of email.